# How to overwrite operator in C++ class with a variadic function?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

C++ newbie here: I want to create a template class to create tensors of different data types and `d` dimensions, where `d` is specified by a shape. For example, a tensor with shape `(2, 3, 5)` has 3 dimensions holding 24 elements. I store all data elements using a 1d vector and want to access elements using the shape information to find the elements.

I would like to overwrite the `()` operator to access the elements. Since the dimensions can vary, so can the number of input parameters for the `()` operator. Technically, I can use a vector as input parameter but C++ also seems to support variadic functions. However, I cannot wrap my head around it.

What I have so far:

```
#ifndef TENSOR_HPP
#define TENSOR_HPP

#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdarg.h>


template <typename T> class Tensor {

    private:
        std::vector<T> m_data;
        std::vector<std::size_t> m_shape;
        std::size_t m_size;
        
    public:
        // Constructors
        Tensor(std::vector<T> data, std::vector<std::size_t> shape);

        // Destructor
        ~Tensor();

        // Access the individual elements                                                                                                                                                                                               
        T& operator()(std::size_t&... d_args);
        
};


template <typename T> Tensor<T>::Tensor(std::vector<T> data, std::vector<std::size_t> shape) {
    // Calculate number of data values based on shape
    m_size = std::accumulate(std::begin(shape), std::end(shape), 1, std::multiplies<std::size_t>());
    // Check if calculated number of values match the actual number
    if (data.size() != m_size) {
        throw std::length_error("Tensor shape does not match the number of data values");
    } 
    // All good from here
    m_data = data;
    m_shape = shape;
}

template <typename T> T& Tensor<T>::operator() (std::size_t&... d_args) {
    // Return something to avoid warning
    return m_data[0];
};

template <typename T> Tensor<T>::~Tensor() {
    //delete[] m_values;
};


#endif
```

No when I do the following:

```
std::vector<float> data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24};
std::vector<std::size_t> shape = {2, 3, 4};
Tensor<float> tensor(data, shape);

tensor(2,0,3); // <-- What I would like to do

// Possible workaround with vector which I would like to avoid
// std::vector<std::size_t> index = {2,0,3};
// tensor(index);
```

I get the error:

```
tensor2.hpp:27:33: error: expansion pattern ‘std::size_t&’ {aka ‘long unsigned int&’} contains no parameter packs
```

What is the correct approach to overwrite the `()` operator using a variadic function?

Comment: How about `Tensor<float, 2, 3, 4>`?

Comment: Your compiler shouldn't allow you to pass a prvalue as a parameter with a non-const qualified reference type...

Comment: @Jarod42 Defining a tensor that way would be fine of course. How would this effect the code. Again, this should be flexible in the sense that I might want to store the 24 values in a `Tensor<float, 2, 12>`, `Tensor<float, 12, 2>`, `Tensor<float, 1, 1, 1, 1, 24>`, `Tensor<float, 1, 12, 1, 2>`, etc. Assume, there will be a change here `template <typename T, ???> class Tensor`, and how would the `()` operator definition look like?

Comment: Terminology: you want to *overload* an operator, not to overwrite (the latter is a non-term).

Comment: What do you want to happen if the shape is {2,3,4} and you try to access tensor(0,0)?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. For the time being it would be fine to throw an error as the number of parameters does not match the number of dimensions. Of course one could argue that his should return a 1d tensor.

Comment: The latter is problematic since a scalar and a 1d tensor are different types, and you don't know which one to return until run time. Unless you are willing to identify scalars with 0d tensors, that is.

Comment: Another approach is to encode the rank of the tensor in the type, so such errors could be caught at compile time. But depending on the task in hand it is not always the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By providing "shape" as template parameter, you might do:

```
// Helper for folding to specific type
template <std::size_t, typename T> using always_type = T;

// Your Tensor class
template <typename T, std::size_t... Dims>
class MultiArray
{
public:

    explicit MultiArray(std::vector<T> data) : values(std::move(data))
    {
        assert(values.size() == (1 * ... * Dims));
    }

    const T& get(const std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Dims)>& indexes) const
    {
        return values[computeIndex(indexes)];
    }
    T& get(const std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Dims)>& indexes)
    {
        return values[computeIndex(indexes)];
    }

    const T& get(always_type<Dims, std::size_t>... indexes) const
    {
        return get({{indexes...}});
    }
    T& get(always_type<Dims, std::size_t>... indexes)
    {
        return get({{indexes...}});
    }

    static std::size_t computeIndex(const std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Dims)>& indexes)
    {
        constexpr std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Dims)> dimensions{{Dims...}};
        size_t index = 0;
        size_t mul = 1;

        for (size_t i = dimensions.size(); i != 0; --i) {
            assert(indexes[i - 1] < dimensions[i - 1]);
            index += indexes[i - 1] * mul;
            mul *= dimensions[i - 1];
        }
        assert(index < (1 * ... * Dims));
        return index;
    }

    static std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Dims)> computeIndexes(std::size_t index)
    {
        assert(index < (1 * ... * Dims));

        constexpr std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Dims)> dimensions{{Dims...}};
        std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Dims)> res;

        std::size_t mul = (1 * ... * Dims);
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i != dimensions.size(); ++i) {
            mul /= dimensions[i];
            res[i] = index / mul;
            assert(res[i] < dimensions[i]);
            index -= res[i] * mul;
        }
        return res;
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> values; // possibly: std::array<T, (1 * ... * Dims)>
};
```

Usage would be similar to

```
std::vector<float> data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24};
MultiArray<float, 2, 3, 4> tensor(data);
std::cout << tensor.get(1, 0, 3); // 16
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/934097ce8bc8dccd)

Comment: OK, wow...this is a lot to digest :). I already have a working solution for matrices (i.e., 2d sensors; where the `()` operator always gets exactly 2 parameters), and I "only" wanted to generalize this solution tensors with arbitrary number of dimensions. I guess I was I bit naive here. With my current (and limited) knowledge of C/C++, I cannot even properly read your code.

Comment: `ComputeIndex`(`es`) is the "algorithm" part to convert linear index to multi-index and vice-versa. I then got `get` taking index as array (2 versions const/non const) and the one you want using `always_type` to get rid of array syntax (and it forward to the array ones).

Comment: Yes, the principle mapping from linear to multidimensional indices I can follow; on paper I already have a solution as the extension to my Matrix/2d-Tensor class. But there's lot of syntax I'm not yet familiar with (e.g., the double curly brackets and all the uses of the ellipses). But that's just something I have to read up on.

Comment: `std::array` is mostly a struct with a C-array, so aggregate initialization need double curly braces. (C-arrays have strange syntax especially for reference, `std::array` has that glitch :-/). Variadic introduces ellipsis usages which might be unfamiliar. Don't hesitate if you have questions.

Comment: Well, like to think that I get the basic idea behind templates and parameter packs. I think it's the combination of both concepts that throw me off. Using [https://cppinsights.io/](https://cppinsights.io/) to look and the instantiated class and functions helped a little bit. But I can properly figure out what the template alias us doing. Is it really need and how would the code change without it?

Answer (score 1):

You can add helper function with as many as overloads to want to calculate proper index to access item:

```
    T& getData(int dim1) { return m_data[dim1];}
    T& getData(int dim1, int dim2) { return m_data[ dim1* m_shape[1] + dim2 ];}
    T& getData(int dim1, int dim2, int dim3) { return m_data[ dim1*m_shape[1]*m_shape[2] + dim2*m_shape[2] + dim3 ];}
```

then `operator()` may look like:

```
    template<class ... Args>                                                                                                                                                                                           
    T& operator()(Args... d_args) {
        static_assert( (std::is_integral_v<Args> && ...) ); // [1]
        return getData(d_args...);
    }
```

by [1] we restrict the use of `()` only with integral types.

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h79drK3co)

Comment: This code will only run without the `static_assert` line as I have gcc 10.2 currently installed. I just wonder, is defining a set of helper functions this way a good general approach. Arguably, I won't need tensors with more then 10 dimensions in practice, but it's not obvious where to place the maximum number of dimensions and thus help functions.

Comment: You can turn on c++17 in 10.2 by `-std=c++17`.

Comment: Ah, I see...that worked! I didn't know what I had to explicitly turn it on.  I only saw [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) that C++17 should be support by 10.2 and was confused.