# Troubles understanding const in c++ (cannot bind non-const lvalue reference)

Tags: c++, c++17, pass-by-reference

I'm trying build a Tensor class in C++. This is only for a personal project to get some practice in C++, and it kind of works, but now I hit some C++ problems that I cannot quite understand. Here's the main structure of my Tensor class with a few functions omitted which shouldn't be relevant.

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T> struct Tensor {
    // Support for up to 5 dimensions
    T& at(std::vector<std::size_t> indices); // Calls the other at() functions depending on the vector size
    T& at(std::size_t d1);
    T& at(std::size_t d1, std::size_t d2);
    T& at(std::size_t d1, std::size_t d2, std::size_t d3);
    T& at(std::size_t d1, std::size_t d2, std::size_t d3, std::size_t d4);
    T& at(std::size_t d1, std::size_t d2, std::size_t d3, std::size_t d4, std::size_t d5);
    Tensor transpose();
    Tensor matmul(Tensor& rhs) {
        rhs.at(0);
        return Tensor();
    }
};
```

When testing `matmul()` for multiplying two tensors, the following code works:

```
void works() {
    Tensor<float> tensor1;
    Tensor<float> tensor2 = tensor1.transpose();
    Tensor<float> tensor3 = tensor1.matmul(tensor2);
}
```

However, the following code where I don't explicitly create a `tensor1` as the transpose of `tensor1` fails:

```
void fails() {
    Tensor<float> tensor1;
    Tensor<float> tensor = tensor1.matmul(tensor1.transpose());
}
```

The first error that is thrown is

```
tensor.test.cpp:26:60: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'Tensor<float>&' to an rvalue of type 'Tensor<float>'
   26 |     Tensor<float> tensor = tensor1.matmul(tensor1.transpose());
      |                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

From my googling and limited understanding of C++, I've tried to change the definition of `matmul()` to

```
Tensor matmul(const Tensor& rhs) { // <-- const added
```

However, if I do this, I get a different error:

```
tensor.hpp: In instantiation of 'Tensor<T> Tensor<T>::matmul(const Tensor<T>&) [with T = float]':
tensor.test.cpp:21:43:   required from here
tensor.hpp:13:15: error: passing 'const Tensor<float>' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   13 |         rhs.at(0);
      |         ~~~~~~^~~
```

**EDIT 1:** Following the comments, using `Tensor matmul(const Tensor& rhs);` adding a `const` definition of all `at()` functions solved my problem. Howver now the code looks loke this:

```
T& at(std::vector<std::size_t> indices);
T& at(std::size_t d1);
T& at(std::size_t d1, std::size_t d2);
T& at(std::size_t d1, std::size_t d2, std::size_t d3);
T& at(std::size_t d1, std::size_t d2, std::size_t d3, std::size_t d4);
T& at(std::size_t d1, std::size_t d2, std::size_t d3, std::size_t d4, std::size_t d5);
        
const T& at(std::vector<std::size_t> indices) const;
const T& at(std::size_t d1) const;
const T& at(std::size_t d1, std::size_t d2) const;
const T& at(std::size_t d1, std::size_t d2, std::size_t d3) const;
const T& at(std::size_t d1, std::size_t d2, std::size_t d3, std::size_t d4) const;
const T& at(std::size_t d1, std::size_t d2, std::size_t d3, std::size_t d4, std::size_t d5) const;
```

which means quite some duplicated code. I wonder if this can be improved.

Answer (score 2):

> From my googling and limited understanding of C++, I've tried to change the definition of matmul() to
>
> ```
> Tensor matmul(const Tensor& rhs); // <-- const added
> ```

Unless `matmul` modifies `rhs`, it indeed shouldn't take a non-const reference. And the parmeter being a non-const reference is indeed the reason why the example didn't work. So, you have come to the correct solution.

> The `at(left)` which calls the `at()` of `this` works.

That's because `matmul` is still a non-const member function. However, does that make sense? Just like the function not modifying `rhs`, does it modify `*this`? I bet not. And given that the function isn't const, you cannot do this:

```
const Tensor tensor;
Tensor tensor3 = tensor.matmul(some_other_tensor);
```

Does that restriction make sense? Probably not.

So, you probably should make it a const member function. That would prevent `at` from working with `*this` as well.

> I've tried setting the input parameters of all `at()` functions to `const` without success.

That doesn't help. What you must do is make it a const member function. But to do that, it must return a const reference.

However, you might need `at` that returns non-const reference too. So how to solve that. I recommend checking how standard library deals with this. Let's look at `std::vector` for example:

```
reference       at( size_type pos );
const_reference at( size_type pos ) const;
```

Would you look at that. There are two overloads. One const and the other non-const. You can follow this example with your tensor class.

Comment: That helped, yes...thanks a lot! The "problem" is that I now have 12 `at()` function, the original 6 non-const ones and now the 6 const ones. Unfortunately, my original question edited which removed my class. I can't see how this new `struct` definition matches my class anymore since one of the issues was support a variable number of dimensions which required me to have 6 original `at()` functions. I know can be solved with [variadic templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67770850/how-to-overwrite-operator-in-c-class-with-a-variadic-function), but I simply couldn't wrap my head around.

Comment: @Christian Does my second edit make things any clearer?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica appreciated! I edited to question with the code snippet with which all es working. I only feel that it result in much duplicated code. As a side question: Is there a reasons why `struct` and instead of  `class` was used?

Comment: @Christian Example code in questions here is supposed to be minimal. Since members being `private` had nothing to do with this question, using `struct` instead made it more minimal.

Answer (score 1):

Your method `at` is not const. Does it modify the Tensor?

If not, you can say so thus:
`T& at(std::size_t d1, std::size_t d2) const;`
and possibly return a `const T&`.

But the problem that you're having is that you're calling a non-const member function (`at`) when on a `const Tensor`

Comment: Adding a const version of each `at()` function worked. But now I have 6 pairs of `at()` functions and quite some (almost) duplicate code. I wonder if this can be optimized.